# Creating secure connection between more than one sql server and databases

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to the MVC world, i am developing an mvc5 code first from database project which i want to to create securely connection between my local server with more than one sql servers, and each server can contains one or more databases.

so can someone clarify me these:
 1. Creating SQL Server Connections[if possible in one entity framework]
 2. Securing the Connections.
 3. if possible how to access the database other then the initial catalog database

Note:
i found to use entity framework to data access , after creating connection then encrypt the connection string by command-line utility, **Aspnet_regiis.exe**
any other techniques rather than this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as securing connections go, all you've got is SSL. Make each SQL Server instance only available via SSL and your connection is as secure as it will ever be. Encrypting the connection string, using a limited access user, etc. are important, but aren't really aspects of securing the *connection*, merely security in general.

For multiple database access via Entity Framework, you just need multiple contexts. Each context belongs to one and only database, but you can have as many contexts as your want. The only thing to be somewhat mindful of is having multiple contexts that you run migrations against. While I believe EF has supported this since version 6, it's still not recommended. Generally, you should only have one context that you run migrations against (the entities that inherently belong to your application), while your other contexts will merely work with existing database created and managed outside of your application. Really, if you think you have a need for multiple migrate-able context in a single project, that's really an argument for splitting up your project into multiple projects.

So, for connecting to an existing database, you just need a regular old `DbContext` subclass, with a couple of tweaks: 1) you need to specify the connection to use manually and 2) you need to disable database initialization. Here's a skeleton of what that looks like:

```
public ExistingDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public ExistingDatabaseContext()
        : base("ConnectionStringName")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ExistingDatabaseContext>(null);
    }

    // DbSets here
}
```